# Request data from Facebook Graph API with multiple different tokens

Tags: facebook, api, facebook-graph-api, token

I request data from my companies facebook page via the **Facebook Graph API**. I have created a **page access token** which has multiple rights. With this token I can read multiple statistical facts showing the performance of the facebook page.

According to the [page access token description](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens?locale=en_US#apptokens) the token is connected to my user account. I am currently an admin of the facebook page of my company. Currently I share the page access token with my colleges.

**Problems:**

- What happens if I am not the admin of the page anymore (e.g. I leave my current company).
- What happens if I delete my facebook account some time in the future?
- I would like to have multiple access tokens in order to use a backup token if neccessary
- What would be the right way to do this?
  I know there is sth. like an **app access token** (see link above).
- I think there is only ONE unique app access token. Can I create multiple tokens?
- Is there a proper way to handle my problem?
- Is the page access token (which I currently use) coupled with my private facebook account? That would be bad!

Comment: Yes, the page token is tied to your personal account. If your personal account gets kicked off the page as an admin, then _that_ page access token has to stop working at this point as well.

Comment: okay, but what is right way to handle these thinks?

Comment: There is no magic way to solve all of those issues. If the page admin leaves the company, then someone else has to take over - and provide an access token based on their account then. This is something you need to handle internally within your organization.